# Gremlin repeat untill the combined weight is greater than x

Tags: graph, gremlin, traversal, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Hello I'm messing around with Gremlin to find paths from one node to another. I have a weighted graph and I need to be able to find all the paths that don't exceed a combined weight.

For instance, if I want all the paths from [A] to [D] that don't exceed the weight of 20

[A] -5-> [B] -15-> [C] -20-> [D] - Would not be valid as it exceeds a combined weight of 20

[A] -5-> [B] -15-> [D] - Would return as its combined weight does not exceed 20.

This is my current query

```
g.V('A').repeat(bothE().otherV().hasLabel('test'))
.until(hasId('D')
.or().loops().is(5)
.or().map(unfold().coalesce(values("weight"),constant(0)).sum().is(gt(20))))
.hasId('D').path().by(valueMap(true))
```

If I remove the below section of the query it returns the same data so there is something wrong with my logic here.

```
.or().map(unfold().coalesce(values("weight"),constant(0)).sum().is(gt(20))))
```

I have considered just filtering this out in the backend API but this doesn't seem like a good practise as a lot of commuting may be wasted as the graph gets larger.

Comment: I can add a full answer a bit later but this is a case where `sack` helps a lot. Something like `bothE().sack(sum).by('weight')`

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where the `sack` step can help a lot. As the query progresses you can continually add the weights found to the current `sack` value.

Using the air-routes data set, where edges have a distance (dist) property, we can write a query similar to yours that will end when it finds the target or the sack has exceeded the allowed maximum. I added all the parts that start with `local` just to show some nicely formatted results. Note the second `has` check. This is needed to make sure we found the intended target in cases where we exited the repeat as the `sack` limit has been exceeded.

```java
g.withSack(0).
  V('3').
  repeat(outE().sack(sum).by('dist').inV().simplePath()).
  until(hasId('49').or().sack().is(gt(6000)).or().loops().is(3)).
  hasId('49').
  local(
    union(
      path().
        by('code').
        by('dist'),
     sack()).
     fold()).
  limit(3)
```

which yields

```
1   [path[AUS, 4901, LHR], 4901]
2   [path[AUS, 748, MEX, 5529, LHR], 6277]
3   [path[AUS, 1209, PIT, 3707, LHR], 4916]
```

To filter out the results where the total exceeds the target, we can move the test to be after the `until`

```java
g.withSack(0).
  V('3').
  repeat(outE().sack(sum).by('dist').inV().simplePath()).
  until(hasId('49').or().loops().is(3)).
  hasId('49').
  where(sack().is(lte(6000))).
  local(
    union(
      path().
        by('code').
        by('dist'),
     sack()).
     fold()).
  limit(3)
```

this time all the results are less than the target of 6000.

```
1   [path[AUS, 4901, LHR], 4901]
2   [path[AUS, 1209, PIT, 3707, LHR], 4916]
3   [path[AUS, 809, ATL, 4198, LHR], 5007]
```

Using this template you can hopefully build a version of your query.

**UPDATED** after discussion in the comments. In the absence of `sack`, you can try something like this. It essentially builds a path of distances, substituting a 0 for where the vertices are, adds that list up, and filters on the sum. It's pretty ugly, but it works!

```java
g.V('3').
  repeat(outE().as('d').inV().simplePath()).
  until(hasId('49').or().loops().is(3)).
  hasId('49').
  where(path().by(constant(0)).by('dist').unfold().sum().is(lte(6000))).
  path().
    by('code').
    by('dist').
  limit(5)
```

The results are

```
1   path[AUS, 4901, LHR]
2   path[AUS, 1209, PIT, 3707, LHR]
3   path[AUS, 809, ATL, 4198, LHR]
4   path[AUS, 755, BNA, 4168, LHR]
5   path[AUS, 1690, BOS, 3254, LHR]
```

Not having support for `sack` is going to make everything a lot more complex but this at least is a possible workaround.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kelvin! This looks exactly like what I am after. Ill go and give it a go

Comment: Im currently using cosmos db and cosmos doesn't support the sack step. I think Ill have to move database as I have experienced a lot of stuff that's not supported with Cosmos.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/support

Comment: Steps like `sack` really are almost essential for this type of query. The alternative is going to be something like collecting a set of paths and then using `sum` and post filtering. It's doable but the query will be more complicated.

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution that does not use `sack`, it's a bit of a complex query but it does work. The `sack` step is so useful in situations like this. I tested my queries using Amazon Neptune and a simple Gremlin console with TinkerGraph.